# Intellij IDEA is not remembering the license/activation code or the opened projects after doing a restart

Tags: intellij-idea

I have entered my Jetbrains license and already created a project three times now. I imported IDE settings which requires a `restart` and when the restart happens *poof* the license/activation key is gone as well as the project that had already been opened.

[image]

This is a strange behavior. I have installed and used the jetbrains products many dozens of times on different computers and had not seen this before.  In fact `DataSpell` and `Pycharm` are working normally on this same computer.

I am on `macOS Monterey 12.5.1`

Comment: Please raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and provide the [IDE logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files) after restarting and reproducing the problem. Also, please attach the IDE settings that you're trying to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been identified as being due to using the "import Settings" feature. When I do that and restart Intellij then the activation code and in fact all past knowledge of my installation are gone.  @CrazyCoder